# Chrome Beta Issue : Inspite of SameSite cookie set to "None" and secure, third party cookie not received

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, web-applications, samesite

I am implementing samesite=None;Secure to a page for cross domain access on chrome beta Version 80.0.3987.78 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)..

While loading the page I see that the attributes are applied correctly, but i still get the console error saying the cookie will not be sent.

Developer Tools->Application->Cookies (My only one cookie, set with samesite="None"; Secure)
[Cookies Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8TzX.png)

The error message from console:

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://mycw125.***.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG4dM.png)

My functionality is broken as well since the cookie is not sent. Could someone help me understand what is going wrong?
I am using chrome Version 80.0.3987.78 (Official Build) beta (64-bit).

We have seen a discrepancy in chrome behavior. This functionality works intermittently as expected, and loads the page with same cookie. It then breaks after that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there maybe another cookie that is being blocked? Does it show up on the Network panel when you click on the affected request? Here are some more ideas to try: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Chrome, the Issues panel shows more information about which cookies and what URLs are involved in issues such as this.